# Is there any function in GSheet to calculate total time spent for current date with two different unit of time in single column?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a GSheet looks like as follows -

| TimeSpent | Date. |
| --- | --- |
| 15 Minute | 26 May 2021 |
| 20 Minute | 26 May 2021 |
| 05 Hours | 26 May 2021 |
| 40 Minute | 25 May 2021 |
| 20 Minute | 24 May 2021 |
| 03 Hours | 23 May 2021 |
| 02 Hours | 20 May 2021 |

Queries - 
(1) Wanted to calculate total time spent for today's date(Current date)
(2) There are two different units of time - Minutes and Hours.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=TEXT(SUM(FILTER(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "Hours"), 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, "\d+")*60, 
 REGEXEXTRACT(A:A, "\d+")*1), B:B=TODAY()))/1440, "[hh] \Hour\s mm \Minut\e\s")
```

[image]

Comment: It's working but only in seperate sheet.

When applying in other existing sheet, solution is not working.

Comment: Did you adjust the range in order to match your data accordingly?

Comment: @MitankDasondhi can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here is the link of the snapshot:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BZQW8UrnjPP0e6G5Ayud-FnmvskPMasu/view?usp=sharing @player0